# Desktop: open file with parameters

Tags: java, pdf, external

I need to open a pdf file on a specific page. There is acrobat command line parameter that does it (it works also in Foxit Reader):

```
Acrobat.exe /A "page=10" "C:\example.pdf"
```

However I don't see how to pass runtime parameters in Desktop class. I would prefer to use it because it lunches default pdf viewer (acrobat reader may not be installed or command line 'acrobat.exe' may not be found).

edit: I found library called "JDIC" but that project seems to be closed. Any other similar solutions?

Comment: You can't have your cake and eat it too. If you want to be reader application-agnostic, then you can't expect to pass command line arguments to it.